# Small values in alluvial plot where decreasing fontsize does not seem to be the solution

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalluvial

I have a question where I am having some trouble with small counts in the category "Worse". Decreasing fontsize even more will decrease the readability (changing the vertical height is also not the solution for me). Does somebody have an ingenious idea of presenting the category (arrow with textbox e.g., but how?)

```
library(alluvial)
library(ggalluvial)
library(ggplot2)

Shortterm<-c("Healed","Impoved","Same","Worse","Healed","Improved","Same","Worse","Healed","Improved","Same","Worse")
Longterm<-c("Healed","Healed","Healed","Healed","Improved","Improved","Improved","Improved","Worse","Worse","Worse","Worse")
Frequence<-c(28,2,0,1,14,6,3,0,1,1,0,0)
Order<-c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
Improved<-c("Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No")

output<-data.frame(Shortterm,Longterm,Frequence,Order,Improved)
output$Improved <- factor(output$Improved, levels = c("Yes", "No"))

ggplot(data = output,
       aes(axis1 = Shortterm, axis2 = Longterm,
           y = Frequence)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Short-term \n ~ 6 months", "Long-term \n ~ 15 years"),expand = c(.2, .05),position="bottom") +
  scale_y_continuous(label = scales::percent_format(scale = 100 /n_id),breaks=c(0,1/4*n_id,1/2*n_id,3/4*n_id,n_id)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Improved)) +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "red"))+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: Worse on the short term has very low counts]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

```
Shortterm<-c("Healed","Improved","Same"," ","Healed","Improved","Same"," ","Healed","Improved","Same"," ")
Longterm<-c("Healed","Healed","Healed","Healed","Improved","Improved","Improved","Improved","Worse","Worse","Worse","Worse")
Frequence<-c(28,2,0,1,14,6,3,0,1,1,0,0)
Order<-c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
Improved<-c("Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No")

output<-data.frame(Shortterm,Longterm,Frequence,Order,Improved)
output$Improved <- factor(output$Improved, levels = c("Yes", "No"))
output$Shortterm <- factor(output$Shortterm, levels = c("Healed","Same","Improved"," "))
output$Longterm  <- factor(output$Longterm,  levels = c("Healed","Same","Improved","Worse"))

n_id <- sum(output$Frequence)
ggplot(data = output,
       aes(axis1 = Shortterm, axis2 = Longterm,
           y = Frequence)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Short-term \n ~ 6 months", "Long-term \n ~ 15 years"),expand = c(.2, .05),position="bottom") +
  scale_y_continuous(label = scales::percent_format(scale = 100 /n_id),breaks=c(0,1/4*n_id,1/2*n_id,3/4*n_id,n_id)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Improved)) +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)),size=3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "red"))+
  theme_minimal() +
  ylab("Operated patients") + xlab("")+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold",size=14))+
  annotate(
    geom = "curve", x = 1, y = 0.4, xend = 1.05, yend = -2, 
    curvature = .3, arrow = arrow(length = unit(2, "mm"))
  )+
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 1.07, y = -2, label = "Worse", hjust = "left",size=3)
```

[image: Solution!]